# Base installed node packages in "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib"

Tags: node.js, npm

I have noticed when installing updated packages
(e.g. `npm install -g ini@1.3.8`
),
they will be placed into `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

However when I undertake vulnerability scanning, older base packages in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib`

Is there anyway (without going to a non-LTS version) these older packages in the npm folder can be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once and what I did was to go to my package.json file, write out the packages I installed earlier, delete the node modules folder and start installing the updated version of the packages

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was inexperience with node and npm

I was not aware that npm was actually installed into the global node-modules directory.

The outdated modules were updated with the following command
`npm upgrade -g npm`